# Using previous Output Directly for Plotting in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I have a problem which is explained by the figure below

[image]

My query is how can I plot the function (%i5) using something like

```
wxplot2d([%],[T2,100,200],[ylabel,"Polytropic co-eff"])$
```

such that I don't have to copy/paste (or re-write) the `f(n)` for the last plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index into the expression with the `part` function. I also have a suggestion for your substitution usage:

```
(%i1) f(n) := T2/T1=(P2/P1)^((n-1)/n)$

(%i2) s : [T1=100, P1=1, P2=8]$

(%i3) solve(f(n), n), s;

(%o4) [n = - log(8) / ( log(0.01 T2) - log(8) ) ]

(%i4) plot2d(part(%o4, 1, 2), [T2, 100, 200], [ylabel, "Polytropic co-eff"])$
```

Output:

[image: Plot of T2 from 100 to 200]

Comment: That's good, but I think a clearer way to get the required part of the expression is just `rhs(%o4[1])`. Note `lhs` and `rhs` are the left and right hand sides of an equation or some other two-sided expressions; see `? lhs` and `? rhs`.

Comment: Why I have to write `rhs(%[1])` instead of just `rhs(%)` as is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343054/how-do-i-use-lhs-and-rhs-to-define-a-function ..Plus can you tell be a suitable way to add gridlines (& any customization I can do with them)

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to use `subst`to get the result given by `solve`:

```
(%i2) f(n) := T2/T1=(P2/P1)^((n-1)/n)$

(%i3) s : [T1=100, P1=1, P2=8]$

(%i4) solve(f(n), n), s;

(%o4) [n = -log(8)/(log(T2/100)-log(8))]

(%i5) plot2d(subst(%,n), [T2, 100, 200], [ylabel, "Polytropic co-eff"])$
```